# Indexing a 4D array using another array of 3D indices

Tags: numpy, matrix-indexing

A have a 4D array `M` (`a x b x c x d`) and an array `I` of indices (`3 x f`), e.g.

```
I = np.array([1,2,3, ...], [2,1,3, ...], [4,1,6, ...])
```

I would like to use `I` to arrive at a matrix `X` that has `f` rows and `d` columns, where:

```
X[0,:] = M[1,2,4,:]
X[1,:] = M[2,1,1,:]
X[2,:] = M[3,3,6,:]
...
```

I know I can use `M[I[0], I[1], I[2]]`, however, I was wondering if there's a more concise solution?

Comment: Your existing solution looks quite concise, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use, for example:

```
I = np.array([[1,2,3], [2,1,3], [4,1,6]])
M = np.ndarray((10,10,10,10))
X = np.array([M[t,:] for t in I])
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do it -

```
import numpy as np

# Get row indices for use when M is reshaped to a 2D array of d-columns format
row_idx = np.sum(I*np.append(1,np.cumprod(M.shape[1:-1][::-1]))[::-1][:,None],0)

# Reshape M to d-columns 2D array and use row_idx to get final output
out = M.reshape(-1,M.shape[-1])[row_idx]
```

As, an alternative to find `row_idx`, if you would like to avoid `np.append`, you can do -

```
row_idx = np.sum(I[:-1]*np.cumprod(M.shape[1:-1][::-1])[::-1][:,None],0) + I[-1]
```

Or little less *scary* way to get `row_idx` -

```
_,p2,p3,_ = M.shape
row_idx = np.sum(I*np.array([p3*p2,p3,1])[:,None],0)
```